# Jess rules reacting to elapsed time

Tags: jess

New to Jess and need rules to fire based on elapsed time.

I.e. if no new facts are entered but a certain amount of time has elapsed, then I need rules to fire.  Example could be if a watchman registers at checkpoint 1 but fails to register at checkpoint 2 and more than 30 minutes have elapsed.

Obvious solution is to post time facts every (say) 5 minutes from a thread, but is there a better way?

Comment: I think the answer is with timer rules, firing once or repeatedly if some condition is true. For a full answer, a little more about the frequency of your watchman registry, the points and duration until alarm might be required: when does supervision start, how long should an alarm be delayed.

Comment: Dear Laune:  I searched for "timer rules" but nothing appeared, are they called something else?  My application has nothing to do with watchmen, but the example captures the essence of the problem:  how to cause a rule to fire  when no new facts have been asserted but time has elapsed.  Or are you agreeing that the best strategy is to create a thread that retracts and then immediately reasserts a time fact every so often?

Comment: Shame on me: I was thinking of another system where there *are* timer rules. However: Jess *does* have the essential features for creating the equivalence of such "timer rules", rules that keep firing after an initial delay and then, optionally, repeatedly with a certain interval. So, one thing you need is to have a way of creating a "trigger fact" that *automatically* depends on the truth values of a set of certain conditions, available in Jess via the *logical* CE. The other thing is a way of running a task repeatedly: use java.util.Timer. - For a full example I'd like to have more details.

Comment: Thanks, I understand how to create timer rules, I was just wondering if there was a better solution.  I found a simple example in the JESS FAQ item 9, "How do I make Jess run forever."

Comment: Due to lack of information I cannot say whether "running forever" is really required in your case. Alternatively, threads monitoring event sources may insert and then call fire until halt. Timers may still access the dormant Working Memory to find overdue situations.